# Facebook iOS sdk friends list returns empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0

i am using this code for getting Facebook friend list in iOS sdk 8.1.

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                              NSDictionary* result,
                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %lu friends", (unsigned long)friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
       NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.objectID);
     }
}];
```

but it returns null value.

Comment: since v2.0, you can only get friends who authorized your app too.

Answer (score 1):

Since Graph API v2.0, the `/{user_id}/friends` endpoint does only return those friends who also gave your app the respective permission.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

> The /me/friends endpoint no longer includes the full list of a person's friends. Instead, it now returns the list of that person's friends who are also using your app.